# How to convert a CFunctionPointer to an EventHandlerUPP?

Tags: swift, callback, event-handling

I have a C function called **Foo_C_Func**, which I need to use as a callback. The rest of the app is coded in Swift. As I understand it, the following code *should* work, but instead I get a compiler error.

```
// typealias makes our function signature easier to read 

typealias Sig = ( EventHandlerCallRef, EventRef, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> OSStatus

// We need to make a CFunctionPointer to the C function 

var ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Sig>.alloc(1)
ptr.initialize( Foo_C_Func )
let c_ptr = COpaquePointer( ptr )

let proc_ptr = CFunctionPointer<Sig>( c_ptr ) as EventHandlerProcPtr

// now we should be able to create the EventHandlerUPP

let handler_upp = NewEventHandlerUPP( proc_ptr )
```

Trying to Build this fails with the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_Foo_C_Func", referenced from:
>
> __TTOFSC10Foo_C_FuncFTVSs14COpaquePointerS_GVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerT___VSs5Int32 in Demo.o
>
> "_NewEventHandlerUPP", referenced from:
>
> __TFC17DemocfMS0_FT_S0_ in Demo.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I also notice when I hover over the last line, that the Xcode tooltip shows the return type of **NewEventHandlerUpp** to be **(EventHandlerProcPtr)** rather than **EventHandlerProcPtr**.

Am I doing it wrong, or is it impossible to create an **EventHandlerUPP** within Swift?

Comment: So far I have been unable to figure out a way for this in Swift 3. Sent a bug report to Apple about it since it also lacks documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these days (Swift 2 and higher) you can use the function directly (declare it "extern" in your C header file, and use "as? EventHandlerUPP" if Swift complains about the type)

Comment: Also, do you really want to use C instead of Swift for this? I believe in my original Xcode project, once Swift 2 was released, I refactored the C files out of existence. If I remember correctly, it is possible these days to use Swift functions to create such pointers.

Comment: I got it to work through Swift easily in 2.0 but Swift 3 seems to change things. I can't use `as? EventHandlerUPP`

Comment: @MAH, I got the old file where I did this to compile without much hassle, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternate answer, if you're using Swift 3. Swift 2 is different than Swift 3, in that the former sucks, whereas the latter is usable.

```
let hotkey_callback: EventHandlerUPP = { _, _, _ in
    // Do stuff
    return noErr
}

var handler: EventHandlerRef? = nil

var spec = EventTypeSpec( 
    eventClass: OSType(kEventClassKeyboard), eventKind:  UInt32(kEventHotKeyPressed) 
)

let status = InstallEventHandler( 
    GetEventDispatcherTarget(), hotkey_callback, 1, &spec, nil, &handler 
)
```

Note that we can use "&" to avoid manually allocating pointers now, and note that adhering to the informal "EventHandlerUPP" protocol is now explicit and doesn't require our manually declaring the Type of each argument. So much easier to read :)

Comment: Looks like this works. I figured it was an issue of Apple keeps changing which values were optional and which weren't. Now I think it's set with Swift3. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this for user MAH, though I have abandoned the original project. The following code compiles in Swift 3. I haven't check whether it works beyond that.

```
import Carbon

func hotkey_callback( _:EventHandlerCallRef?, _ event:EventRef?, _ context:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>? ) -> OSStatus {
    // Do stuff
    return noErr
}

let handler_ref_ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<EventHandlerRef?>( allocatingCapacity: 1 )

let spec_ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<EventTypeSpec>( allocatingCapacity: 1 )

spec_ptr.pointee = EventTypeSpec( eventClass: OSType( kEventClassKeyboard ), eventKind:  UInt32( kEventHotKeyPressed ) )

let hotkey_callback_pointer = hotkey_callback as! EventHandlerUPP

let status = InstallEventHandler( GetEventDispatcherTarget(), hotkey_callback_pointer, 1, spec_ptr, nil, handler_ref_ptr )
```

Comment: While this does compile, it unfortunately crashes with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` on `let hotkey_callback_pointer = hotkey_callback as! EventHandlerUPP`

Comment: I vaguely recall some issues with access in my original version. Is the function you are using global and "public"?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes it is. This problem is only limited to Swift 3. I'm thinking that this may be a bug with Apple. But casting a public function to `EventHandlerUPP` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah, could be a bug. As a workaround, does using "let hotkey_callback_pointer = unsafeBitCast( hotkey_callback, EventHandlerUPP.self )" work?

Comment: Just tried it, looks like the same crash. Very frustrating.

Comment: Bummer :( I'm not sure what to suggest. Has Apple added any new calls? Carbon API so awkward to use, maybe Apple added a block based version?

Comment: Not sure, I've filed a bug report. The other issue is when looking up the "new documentation" with Swift 3, I can't seem to find anything on EventHandlerUPP. Just AEEventHandlerUPP which is a whole different thing.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. The function signature has changed. It uses optionals in Swift 3.

Comment: I updated my answer. Notice the signature for "hotkey_callback" has "?" for the params now. On my system, it runs without error... Still don't know 100% if it works, but it doesn't throw a runtime error.

Comment: Perfect! Compiles and works at run time too. Thanks! Not sure how you found it.

Comment: :) Actually I just command-clicked "EventHandlerUPP" to see if Apple had any comments in the source code, and noticed that the definition for the C "convention" on the line above it was a bit different then the func we were using.

Comment: I tried that. I wonder why I'm having issues on my end. Oh well, thanks for the help!

Comment: @MAH, probably because this API is confusing as heck, and I looked at it with fresh eyes. I imagine you're fatigued. I know I had a nasty time with the original project. Happy it's working anyways :)

Comment: You're right. I just found it. I feel like an idiot. Thanks again. It's 4 am here, time to knock out.

Comment: Ha, well I abandoned my own project partly because this API made me feel like an idiot quite a lot myself. Sleep well!

Comment: Swift 3 sucks way, way, way less. I'm posting an alternate answer here